# Whats the difference between EOS signature and ethereum signature

Tags: eosio.token

As I see, both use secp256k1 **signcompact** method

```
So can I use ethereum crypto package when make an EOS transfer?
```

the below source code **sign**

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/crypto/secp256k1/secp256.go